# How to disable updates during initialization time?

Tags: knockout.js

I've worked with knockout.js to create a gui that enables the user to filter through his data by a lot of different topics. Most of these topics are represented by combobox items, which are select items in html.

I used knockout to subscribe to changes in all of the filter selects. The subscription event just calls a function which collects the filter setting, sends this to the server via ajax and gets a list of items satisfying the filter back.

Additionally the data from the server contains also the available filter topics for each select.

I always wondered about the startup speed, because it really took a while to the gui being fully available. A short while ago I set a breakpoint in the data delivery function and was quite a bit suprised to see it being called about 20 times at startup. :-(

How can I prevent this?

```
var viewModel = {
   entries: ko.observableArray(),           // this is receiving the filtered items

   selectedMode: ko.observable(null),          // Filter 1 initialized to null
   selectedSubMode: ko.observable(null),       // Filter 2 initialized to null
   .
   . 
   availableModes: ko.observableArray(),       // Available filter items 1.
   availableSubModes: ko.observableArray(),    // Available filter items 2.
};
```

The html element is bound like this:

```
<select 
    id="selectMode" 
    tabindex="1" 
    data-bind="options: availableModes, 
               value: selectedMode, 
               optionsCaption: 'Any'"
>
</select>
```

At loading time of the page I issue a single Load of the selectedItems with all selects being "null". So the first page of all data available is returned and I set the availableModes and availableSubModes to the available items returned in the data.

Then a type of iteration starts:

The first select box changes its display to the "Any" value which I set in the binding as optionsCaption. And this seems to trigger a change event. This starts again the request to the server and the next select item is set to "Any". This repeats itself for all select elements.

Does anyone have an idea how I can prevent this from happening?

My first idea was to disable updates in knockout during loading of the data and force an update after the update is finished. But I could not find a suitable method for that.

Thanks for any hints...

Comment: How do you subscribe to drop-down changes?

Comment: I use the following for each of the select items: 


viewModel.selectedMode.subscribe(function () {
   viewModel.loadData();
});

loadData is the function that sends the request to the server and uses the returned data.

Comment: Just a thought... what if instead of subscribing to observables you subscribe to drop-downs' change events?

Comment: @RomanBataev - That kinda defeats the purpose of using KO.

Comment: @madcapnmckay - How so? You still use ko's "event" binding, and this is a perfectly legitimate use case when you need to subscribe to changes explicitly made by the user rather than all changes of the observable.

Comment: @RomanBataev -  Ah I was thinking you meant $("#foo").change(). I try to avoid using vanilla jquery event bindings as it promotes coupling between the viewmodel and the markup. Using the ko event binding is fine, but in this case not needed since the options binding uses the change event and the problem was related to how that works.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your full code with the subscribe methods etc it's hard to say exactly what's wrong. However I noticed one part where you mentioned that the select gets set to "Any" which triggers a change event. I think I can explain this based on what you describe.

From the KO options binding docs.

> KO will prefix the list of items with one that displays the text
>   “Select an item…” and has the value undefined. So, if myChosenValue
>   holds the value undefined (which observables do by default), then the
>   dummy option will be selected.

This means that setting the selectedMode value to null doesn't match the value of "Any". The binding tries to match up your existing value, it can't so it sets the selectMode to undefined and this triggers the change.

Take this jsfiddle. You can see the server fetch log statement fire. If you remove the selectedMode null assignment the log statement doesn't fire.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/H7jzd/

If this doesn't fully resolve things, fork that fiddle and include your full subscribe setup and some fake ajax statement, we should be able to get it working.

Hope this helps